# Using PowerShell (5.1) to EDIT outlook PST path

Tags: powershell, outlook, pst

I know how to add or remove a store with PowerShell using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, but I haven't found any information about *changing* values.
I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace#methods but I don't see a method available for setting properties.

Context: User's PST files have been moved from one path to another. I'm trying to avoid disruption wherever possible, so I'm writing a PS script to move the PST files, and then update Outlook with the new path.

Since removing and re-adding the stores will break user-defined stuff like rules, I'm hoping for a way to change existing store filepaths that will require no user action.

Is this possible at all?

As a second option, can I pull the existing rules, and modify them (or recreate them)?

Answer (score 0):

PST store entry id embeds the PST path in it (you can see it in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - I am its author - click IMessage / IMAPIFolder / IMsgStore button, select `PR_STORE_ENTRYID`, click "..." next to the Value edit box).

If a rule includes a store id (e.g. copy / move message action), you would need to reset / recreate the rule.

I you don't want to remove / add a store, can reset the store location using [ProfMan](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman.htm) library (I am also its author) directly in the profile section in the registry. See https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/profman_examples.htm#example2 for an example on how to read PST paths. You can modify the script to set the path instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.